# 2 setTimeout in Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I manage to create my first function to hide and display div, But when I try to use 2 setTime out the other div is loading infinitely, What I need to do is to display div in diffrent set of time, any idea ?

Here is JS my code

```
function showDiv1() {
  // If there are hidden divs left
  if ($('.forHide:hidden').length) {
    // Fade the first of them in
    $('.forHide:hidden:first').fadeIn();
    if ($('.forHide:hidden').length >= 1) {
      $(".forHide").fadeOut(1500, function() {});
    }
    // And wait one second before fading in the next one
    myVar = setTimeout(showDiv1, 100);

  }
}

function showDiv2() {
  // If there are hidden divs left
  if ($('.forSlowMo:hidden').length) {
    // Fade the first of them in
    $('.forSlowMo:hidden:first').fadeIn();
    if ($('.forSlowMo:hidden').length >= 1) {
      $(".forSlowMo").fadeOut(1500, function() {});
    }
    // And wait one second before fading in the next one
    setTimeout(showDiv2, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: What condition should stop the recursion in `showDiv2`?

Comment: `setTimeout(showDiv1, 100)` doesn't wait 1 second, it wait `0.1` second.

Comment: What do you mean `the other div is loading infinitely`? I'm having a hard time picturing that.

Comment: `setTimeout` is only called if it's hidden - the 'fadeIn()' makes it not hidden = no infinite loop

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hd8q1mox/

Comment: in my browser the showDiv2 is blinking or changing infinitely

Comment: Do you have more than one `.forSlowMo`?  Because you show the first one then immediately hide *all* of them if there's more than one (one or more still hidden).

Comment: Yes I have its 3 .forSlowMo showing at the speed of 100 
and .forHide showing at the speed of 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `.fadeIn` of the first item, if there are any more hidden, the code currently fades them all out:

```
 $('.forSlowMo:hidden:first').fadeIn();
 if ($('.forSlowMo:hidden').length >= 1) {
    // this line selects all, including the one just shown
    $(".forSlowMo").fadeOut(1500, function() {});
 }
```

You need to exclude the one you've just shown:

```
 var x = $('.forSlowMo:hidden:first').fadeIn();
 if ($('.forSlowMo:hidden').length >= 1) {
    $(".forSlowMo").not(x).fadeOut(1500, function() {});
 }
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hd8q1mox/1/

In the fiddle, I've removed the .forHide part so you can see the difference on the .slowMo as they appear on top of each other.